# Copy data from SFTP to ADLS Gen 2 via ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, sftp, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake

I have around 200GB of data in SFTP server in .gz format. I need to copy that into ADLS via ADF. what would be dataset file format that needs to be taken like binary or .csv?
The file extenstion should also be the same .gz format when it is copied in adls.

What is quickest way to achieve this in ADF? If not, ADF what other tools or resources can we use to achieve this

Comment: Since it is blind copy, you can use binary dataset format in ADF

Comment: Have you tried any approach/effort? Share the blockers/errors that occurred during the implementation.

Comment: Regarding the question about region, yes it matters a little, even though copy automatically chooses the most optimal region to perform the data movement operation based on the location of the source and sink data stores. There might be a slight difference in latency copying from far away locations.

Comment: @Nandan - I have used csv delimited text. this would also work right

Answer (score 1):

You can use copy activity with **SFTP Connector** and use that connector for source dataset.

- Enter the compression type as `gzip(.gz)` in source dataset.

[image]

**Source Dataset configuration**

```json
{
"name": "DelimitedText66",
"properties": {
"linkedServiceName": {
"referenceName": "LS-SFTP",
"type": "LinkedServiceReference"
},
"annotations": [],
"type": "DelimitedText",
"typeProperties": {
"location": {
"type": "AzureBlobFSLocation",
"fileName": "Book1.xlsx.gz",
"fileSystem": "con1"
},
"columnDelimiter": ",",
"compressionCodec": "gzip",
"escapeChar": "\\",
"quoteChar": "\""
},
"schema": [
{
"type": "String"
},
{
"type": "String"
}
]
}
}
```

- Similarly, create a linked service for ADLS and create a sink dataset.
- Use these datasets in copy activity and execute the pipeline to copy from SFTP to ADLS.

> would the region of the data matter here?

It depends on the location of your SFTP server and the ADLS account. If the SFTP server and the ADLS account are in the same region, the data transfer may be faster.

Reference:

1. [azure-docs/connector-sftp.md at main · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs (github.com)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/data-factory/connector-sftp.md)
2. [azure-docs/connector-azure-data-lake-storage.md at main · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs (github.com)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage.md)

Comment: So, would specifying the compression type as gzip(.gz) in source dataset matter?

Comment: also in sink dataset. what does compression type do?

Comment: Can we do this via Azure Databricks?

Comment: Refer this [document](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/data-factory/v1/data-factory-supported-file-and-compression-formats.md) for more details on compression type